# Set ejabberd as a xmpp proxy for Facebook Chat with X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM

Tags: facebook, xmpp, ejabberd, facebook-chat, x-facebook-platform

I want to use ejabberd for xmpp proxy with Facebook Chat

**It already work but** unfornunately when i ask for authentication with chat.facebook.com **the X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM mechanism is not possible**

This is facebook answer for mechanism :

```
<mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism>
```

The complet facebook answer :

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' sid='XXX' wait='300' requests='2' inactivity='30' maxpause='120' polling='2' ver='1.6' from='chat.facebook.com' secure='true' authid='433584819' xmpp:version='1.0'>
    <stream:features xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>
        <mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>
            <mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism>
            <mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism>
        </mechanisms>
        <register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/>
    </stream:features>
</body>
```

Do you know why the X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM mechanism is not in the list ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK ejabberd does not support routing in BOSH. You can only connect to the XMPP domains hosted on your ejabberd sever over BOSH. What you need is a BOSH connection manager like Punjab.

Alex

Comment: @Alex is it possible to handle the connections created in ejabber using punjab too ?

Comment: @Hunt You can connect to ejabberd through Punjab also, if that's what you mean.

Comment: so if i wanna go for a custom chat + facebook chat then do i need to user two different end point urls one which connects to ejabberd and other for custom XMPP chat ?

Comment: @Hunt Depends on many factors. But I wouldn't proxy the traffic through Punjab when not unnecessary. So 2 endpoints can make sense, and I see no problem with it.